# Not required field in manyToOne relation entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have class IP. One of this class parameter is User class.

I would like to have relation between user and ip.
I would like to add entity ip with user related, but the user entity is not required in form. So I should be able to add IP entity without user related (In db in ip table in user foreign key column should be null).

How can I achive this in hiberanate/jpa

My Ip class:

```
@Entity
public class Ip {

/** The id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long id;

@Column(length = 50)
@Constraints.Required
public String address;

@ManyToOne(optional = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public User user;

// other code //
```

}

and User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="common__User")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String email;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @Constraints.Required
    public Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    public Department department;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public List<Role> role;

    @Constraints.Required
    public boolean system;

    @Constraints.Required
    public boolean active;
}
```

My method to persist IP entity

```
public void toDataBase() {
    JPA.em().persist(this);
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [models.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=customer, rootBeanClass=class models.User, messageTemplate='error.required'}
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class models.User, messageTemplate='error.required'}
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class models.User, messageTemplate='error.required'}
]]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [models.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=customer, rootBeanClass=class models.User, messageTemplate='error.required'}
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class models.User, messageTemplate='error.required'}
        ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='error.required', propertyPath=password, rootBeanClass=class models.User, messageTemplate='error.required'}
]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.9.Final.jar:3.6.9.Final]
```

And mysql db structure

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default
1   id  bigint(20)          No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
2   address varchar(50) utf8_general_ci     Yes NULL
3   user_id bigint(20)          Yes NULL
```

Please help

Comment: Have you checked if there are any constraints in the database? Another guess is that the list is null and the field does not allow nulls. Initialize the list or provide the null alloved annotation.

Comment: What do you mean by `not mandatory field` ? You mean to say, u don't want to add it in database or something else ?

Comment: I mean like use annotation @Column(nullable = true)

Comment: when does the exception occur? while persisting an Ip? is a User object implicitly created by the framework you use? Mapping and the code you attach seems ok.

Comment: exception occur while persisting IP entity

Comment: kamuflage661 I've added annotation like You write, but I am getting an error: `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property: models.Ip.user`